# Closed unit balls

Tags: tikz-pgf

I used some prepare code and result is illustrated as follow.
To fill inside the balls, what should we do?
[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Unit circle plot style
\pgfplotsset{unit circle/.style={width=4cm,height=4cm,axis lines=middle,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,axis equal,enlargelimits,xmax=1,ymax=1,xmin=-1,ymin=-1,domain=0:pi/2}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (prev); % Store previous plot position
    \foreach \p / \t in {2/1, 1/2, 0.0001/\infty} { % Loop through the plots to draw
        % \p is the exponent in the function to plot
        % \t is the p parameter to print
        \begin{axis}[at={(prev)},unit circle,anchor=west]
            \foreach \ss in {1,-1} {
            \foreach \cs in {1,-1} {
                \addplot[] ({\cs*(cos(deg(x)))^\p},{\ss*(sin(deg(x))^\p});
            }
            }
        \end{axis}
        \node[below=0.5cm, anchor=base] at (current axis.south) {$p=\t$}; % Print p
        \coordinate[right=0.5cm] (prev) at (current axis.east) ; % Set position for next plot
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile this example by itself? It doesn't for me.

Comment: Yes, however, I can't overcome to it. All I know is to use the fill command, that did not work.

Comment: With \addplot you will need [fill between].  Or you could reproduce the figures outside the axis environment by saving some of the coordinates.

Comment: Is it a requirement to plot using that specific parameterization, or can you just draw those three shapes (diamond, circle, square)?

Comment: After deleting the two U+200E characters around `{` in `\foreach \p / \t in {2/1 ...`, the example now compiles.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is finally solved. I changed only one line!

```
‎\addplot[fill=gray‎‎] ({\cs*(cos(deg(x)))^\p},{\ss*(sin(deg(x))^\p})‎\closedcycle‎;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved with tkz-euclide -- a rough similarity is below which can be adapted to the above requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or another class
\usepackage{xcolor} % before tikz or tkz-euclide if necessary

\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % no need to load TikZ
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} %if there are problems with the active characters
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \d/\x/\y in {2/-2/0,3/1/0,4/5/0}{%
        \tkzDefPoint(\x,\y){K}
        \tkzDefShiftPoint[K](0:\d){M}
        \tkzDefSquare(K,M)\tkzGetPoints{N}{O}
        \tkzDrawPolygon[color=red,fill=green](K,M,N,O)
        \tkzLabelSegment[below](K,M){Square side=\d cm}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or another class
\usepackage{xcolor} % before tikz or tkz-euclide if necessary

\usepackage{tkz-euclide} % no need to load TikZ
\usepackage{multirow}
\usetikzlibrary{babel} %if there are problems with the active characters
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}\hspace{-4cm}
\tkzInit[xmax=2,ymax=3,xmin=-2.5,ymin=-3]
\tkzDrawXY[label={}]
\tkzDefPoint(-2,-2){K}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[K](0:4){M}
\tkzDefSquare(K,M)\tkzGetPoints{N}{O}
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red,fill=green](K,M,N,O)
%\tkzLabelSegment[below, yshift=-1.5cm](K,M){p=1}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}\hspace{-3cm}
\tkzInit[xmax=2.5,ymax=3,xmin=-3,ymin=-3]
\tkzDrawXY[label={}]
\tkzDefPoint(0,-(sqrt(18))/2){K}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[K](45:3){M}
\tkzDefSquare(K,M)\tkzGetPoints{N}{O}
\tkzDrawPolygon[color=red,fill=green](K,M,N,O)
%\tkzLabelPoint[below, yshift=0cm](K){p=2}
\end{tikzpicture} \hspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzInit[xmax=2.5,ymax=3,xmin=-2.5,ymin=-3]
\tkzDrawXY[label={}]
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){K}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[K](0:2){M}
\tkzDrawCircle[color=red,fill=green](K,M)
%\tkzLabelPoint[below, yshift=-2cm](K){p=}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how this answers the question. It's not the same diagram.

Comment: it is not -- just a rough similarity the third figure is same-- the first two figures can be  edited --will do it  if it suits the OP